# Prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{C_{1}})=\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}.$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ be a probability space and let $\left\{X_\alpha:\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}\right\}$ be a collection of random variables on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ and $\left\{Y_\beta:\beta\in \Gamma_{2}\right\}$ be another collection of random variables on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ where both $\Gamma_{1}$ and $\Gamma_{2}$ are nonempty set.

Whether we have the following conclusion:

$\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}$  and $\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\beta\in \Gamma_{2}} Y_{\beta}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}$ are independent w.r.t. $P$
$\Leftrightarrow $ For each finite subset of $\Gamma_{1}$, $\mathcal{I}$ and each finite subset of $\Gamma_{2}$, $\mathcal{J},$ $\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{i\in\mathcal{I} } X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}$ and $\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{j\in\mathcal{J} } Y_{j}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}$  are independent w.r.t. $P$.

---

"$\Rightarrow $" is obviously.

"$\Leftarrow $" Let $$\mathcal{C_{1}}=\left\{A:A\in\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \mathcal{I}} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right),\mathcal{I}\text { is any finite subset of  }\Gamma_{1}\right\};$$
$$\mathcal{C_{2}}=\left\{B:B\in\sigma\left(\bigcup_{j\in \mathcal{J}} Y_{j}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right),\mathcal{J}\text { is any finite subset of  }\Gamma_{2}\right\}.$$

Since $\mathcal{C_{1}}$ and $\mathcal{C_{2}}$ are $\pi$-systems,also $\mathcal{C_{1}}$ and $\mathcal{C_{2}}$ are independent w.r.t. $P$, we have $\sigma(\mathcal{C_{1}})$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{C_{2}})$ are independent w.r.t. $P$.
If we can prove that $$\sigma(\mathcal{C_{1}})=\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}\text{ and }\sigma(\mathcal{C_{2}})=\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\beta\in \Gamma_{2}} Y_{\beta}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \},$$
then the equivalence holds.

---

The next question is how to prove that $\sigma(\mathcal{C_{1}})=\sigma \left \{ \bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right ) \right \}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let $A\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right )$. So, in particular, there exists $\alpha_A\in \Gamma_1$ such that $A\in X_{\alpha_A}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right )$. So, $A\in \sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \{\alpha_A\}} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)\subset \mathcal{C}_l$. This gives
$$
\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right )\subset \mathcal{C}_l
$$
and
$$
\sigma\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in \Gamma_{1}} X_{\alpha}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right )\right)\subset \sigma\left(\mathcal{C}_l\right).
$$

Next, let $A\in \mathcal{C}_l$. So, $ A\in \sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in I_A} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)$ for some choice of finite subset $I_A$ of $\Gamma_1$. But,
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I_A} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\subset\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma_1} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)
$$
so
$$
\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in I_A} X_{i}^{-1}\left ( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)\subset\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma_1} X_{i}^{-1}\left( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)
$$
and $A\in \sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma_1} X_{i}^{-1}\left( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)$. This, gives
$$
\mathcal{C}_l
\subset\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma_1} X_{i}^{-1}\left( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right)
$$
and
$$
\sigma(\mathcal{C}_l)
\subset\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i\in \Gamma_1} X_{i}^{-1}\left( \mathcal{B(\mathbb{R})} \right)\right).
$$